# MySQL disappearing records after UPDATE

Tags: mysql

Disappearing is mystical. *Quate`s from SQL log from /var/log/mysql*

> 141102 20:08:10   270328 Connect  root@1.2.3.4 on database
>           270328 Query    UPDATE `table` SET `player_level` = '23', `player_xp` = '93600', `player_prestige` = '0', `player_name` = 'Dariune', `player_last_date` = '2014-11-02 20:08:10' WHERE `player_id` = 'Dariune'
>           270328 Quit

After 14 hours without UPDATE, DELETE or something similar record was missed and INSERTED new again.

I have all MySQL logs and NO updates with that record was done. No dublicates, no record nothing, gone like never existed.

*Sorry for my poor English.*

Comment: Have you any triggers?

Comment: Gone, or reverted to what it was before the update? Update only, well, updates. To insert or delete records use insert or delete respectively.

Comment: @starko - If I understood correctly - No.

Comment: @GolezTrol - Gone, because it no more in my table, becouse before it was 0, 0, 0 but I haven't found any record with "player_id" = "Dariune"

Comment: But the log only says that the update statement was executes. I think it doesn't say that any record was found. So maybe the record didn't exist at all.

Comment: All UPDATE is executed after SELECT'ing information and if it's found in DB only then UPDATE'd

Comment: UPDATE queries are logged even if they haven't found a row to update. It is possible, that the row already haven't existed at the time of this query.

Comment: Row existed, becouse information from row was SELECTED before.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not crazy, it happened to someone else ! On UPDATE where id=XX, the record disappears without any log anywhere.
I have perhaps a clue: my Where clause was id = 'XX'. I've just switched to id = XX.
I hope it was the issue...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).